# Grub prompt after Installation

Tags: grub

Installed elementary OS to dual boot with Windows 8.1. After the request to reboot there is only a grub prompt. Now I cannot access Windows.

Any solutions to allow access to Windows? And elementary OS?

Thanks,

oDK

Comment: Did you install elementaryOS in UEFI mode or Legacy? Also what is the context of the grub prompt?

Comment: looking at this poor question, and the obvious fact that you didnt saw a windows option in grub...  I'm sure you just clicked 'next, next..' and deleted windows because I tried elementary installer just now and works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen to me a couple of times. Usually when I've been manually configuring partitions and made a mistake somewhere.

`ls` in grub will show you all the partitions on each hard drive that grub can find.

If you think you know what the boot partition is for elementary OS e.g (hd0, gpt4) then you can boot by telling grub where to load it's configfile:

`configfile (hd0, gpt4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Maybe someone else can chime in about how to boot Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happening to me when installing Ubuntu, **I have not done it in ElementaryOS**, but I believe it should be the same thing on ElementaryOS

**install Boot-Repair**

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

**Using Boot-Repair**

Recommended repair

launch Boot-Repair by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

> Warning: the default settings are the ones used by the "Recommended
>   Repair". Changing them may worsen your problem. Don't modify them
>   before creating a BootInfo URL, and asking for advice on Ubuntu Forums
>   Absolute Beginners Section or in Installation and Upgrades.